# Does a mirror port keep VLAN tags?

Tags: vlan, brocade, mirror

I have the following config on a Brocade XMR, running IronWare 5.6.0c.

Will the traffic mirrored to e 1/13 keep it's VLAN tags, so I can distinguish where it came from? Or will the tags be stripped and all be untagged?

And for bonus points, if it will be untagged, is there any way to keep the tags?

```
mirror ethernet 1/13

interface ethernet 2/16
 enable
 mon ethernet 1/13 both
!
```

--

```
#show vlan e 1/13
VLAN: 1  Untagged

#show vlan e 2/16
VLL name                   XXXXXX, VLL ID:               150, VLAN:  910    Tagged
VLL name                   YYYYYY, VLL ID:               151, VLAN:  911    Tagged
VLAN: 37  Tagged
VLAN: 90  Tagged
VLAN: 129  Tagged
VLAN: 256  Tagged
VLAN: 257  Tagged
VLAN: 280  Tagged
VLAN: 287  Tagged
VLAN: 290  Tagged
VLAN: 291  Tagged
VLAN: 1014  Tagged
```

Comment: @RedShift That is the answer I am looking for I think.  Make it an answer and I will accept it. Use this link for docs... http://www.brocade.com/downloads/documents/html_product_manuals/NI_05600_SWITCHING/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#context=NetIron_05600a_SwitchingGuide&file=Port_Params.03.15.html#1086983

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.brocade.com/downloads/documents/html_product_manuals/NI_05600_SWITCHING/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm) says: "NOTE: If a port is configured as a mirror port, all traffic sent from that port will retain the encapsulation of the port being monitored and not add the encapsulation of the Egress port.". So it's a 1:1 packet copy, any tagging is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

On Cisco devices, when configuring SPAN-mirroring . The packets are received in untagged format and an "encapsulation replicate" command must be defined to keep them tagged.

On Brocade, it is probably similar. 
As for keeping the tags maybe this will help
http://community.brocade.com/t5/Design-Build/How-To-Configure-VLAN-Mirroring-on-the-NetIron-Platform/ta-p/36798

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this would be an exception on Brocade, but you should receive all VLAN tags on mirror port. No VLAN membership setup is needed in mirror port.